# Modify Quickfix to ignore paths outside project

Tags: quickfix

I have been learning about quickfix recently, trying to make it work well with `pytest` to that end I provided my own `makeprg` and `efm`.
So far everything is great except that pytest frequently traces error back to a library that I use within my project and when I run `:make` vim open a new buffer of file in that 3rd party library.

What I'd like to do is make vim ignore error paths that are not in my project, which in case of `pytest` happen to be error that start with absolute path rather than relative one.

Is that possible?

Not sure if this is of any relevance to this but this is my efm `%f:%l:\ %m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a marker to ignore a matched file: `%-G` (see `:help efm-ignore`).

As you want to ignore a line that contains an absolute path, just ignore anything matching `/.*`. For errorformat this is written as `/.%#`.

Combined together:

```
:set errorformat=%-G/.%#,%f:%l:\ %m
```

If you are on Windows, maybe the following (can't test):

```
:set errorformat=%-G.:\\.%#,%f:%l:\ %m
```

Comment: took we a while to test this out but works like a charm, now my quickfix looks much cleaner